# What should I do to make the iPhone always remember I have trusted the Windows 10 device?

Tags: windows, iphone

I didn't have to do this before, but since a few days ago, the iPhone started to ask me to "Trust This Computer?" every time when I connect it to my Windows 10 laptop to access photos on the phone. I don't remember anything I did differently.

What should I do to make the iPhone always remember I have trusted the Windows 10 device?

iOS Version: 11.3 (15E216)

Comment: Edit your question to include which version of iOS you are using.  The current iOS introduced a security feature, that is enabled by default, and would explain this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, ensure you have the most recent version of iTunes installed on your machine, then:

1. Plug in your device.
2. Type Windows Key + R, then type `devmgmt.msc` in the box which appears, hit enter.
3. Click Portable Devices.
4. Right click on Apple iPad/iPhone/iPod, then Update Driver Software.
5. Choose "Browse my computer for driver software"
6. Navigate to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile  Device Support\Drivers"

This should install the baseline iTunes framework required for remembering your computer's unique address. You may need to trust the computer once more after having updated the Apple iPhone driver software.

Note: You may need to search in some other tabs in Device Manager to find the Apple device, such as Unknown Devices. You'll know when you've found it.

Comment: I don't have iTunes installed and I don't really need it.

Comment: iTunes contains much of the software stack which is really the only way to ensure full compatibility. Try skipping that step and just walk through Device Manager. See what happens.

Comment: Just tried with all the steps without installing iTunes. It says 'The best drivers for your device are already installed. (MTP USB Device) and the problem is still there.

Comment: According to Apple, "Your iOS device remembers the computers you've chosen to trust." so I would advice biting the bullet at this point and trying with iTunes, after rebooting. If the problem persists you can always uninstall.